# agGrid add fontawesome icon to header, not cell and not all columns

Tags: vue.js, header, icons, ag-grid

I did my research on google, but found nothing helpful.I want to add another vue component for this problem, i tried with headerComponentFramework but it did not work.

grid.vue

```
{
        headerName: '',
        field: '',
        headerComponentFramework: customHeader,
},
```

customHeader.vue

```
<template>
<span class="icon">
    <fa-icon icon="tag"/>
  </span>
</template>
```

agGrid empty now and Also my console is here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTzCp.png)

Comment: can you post your header component.js 
? Also check out an example here - https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#example-header-component

Comment: documantation little bit complex for me and i tried to create as vue component not js file.I imported to my parent page(grid.vue) and it doesnt work.Can't i add as vue component when i add to icon to header of column?

Comment: Your custom vue component should contain html + javascript for it to work. Adding the updated link https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/#vueCellEditing . You can follow the exact code from documentation and it should work for you. Do check out the 'age' column and the file customHeaderVue.js you can do it!